# How can I have the Accordion row colors alternate between two colors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using ui material accordion to create a page. Here is a part of my code:

```
    root: {
        border: '5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        '&:not(:last-child)': {
            borderBottom: 0,
        },
        '&:before': {
            display: 'none',
        },
        '&$expanded': {
            margin: 'auto',
        },
    },
    expanded: {},
})(MuiAccordion);

const AccordionSummary = withStyles({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .08)',
        borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)',
        marginBottom: -1,
        minHeight: 56,
        '&$expanded': {
            minHeight: 56,
        },
        fontSize: 14,
    },
    content: {
        '&$expanded': {
            margin: '12px 0',
        },
    },
    expanded: {},
})(MuiAccordionSummary);

const AccordionDetails = withStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}))(MuiAccordionDetails);

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    headerTitle: {
        padding: '0 10px',
    },
    headerTitleTxt: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#999'
    },
    headerItem: {
        fontSize: 14,        
        padding: '0 5px',
        color: '#333'
    },
    expandedPanel:{
        backgroundColor: '#C5CAE9'
    }
});

export default function ProjectAccordions(props) {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState();
    const classes = useStyles();

    const handleChange = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
        setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Accordion square expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1')}>
                <AccordionSummary className={expanded === 'panel1' && classes.expandedPanel} aria-controls="panel1d-content" id="panel1d-header">
                    <Grid container direction="row"  alignItems="flex-start">
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Typography variant="button">Duration</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                            <Typography className={classes.headerItem} variant="subtitle1">xxx</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={3} className={classes.headerTitle} container justify="flex-start" alignItems="center" direction="row">
                            <Typography className={classes.headerTitleTxt} variant="subtitle1">xxx</Typography>
                            <NumberFormat
                                className={classes.headerItem}
                                value=2
                                prefix={'$'}
                                type="text"
                                thousandSeparator={','}
                                displayType="text"
                                decimalScale={xxx>1000?0:2}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item container displayType='row' alignItems='center' xs={2} className={classes.headerTitle}>
                            <Typography className={classes.headerTitleTxt} variant="subtitle1">xxx: </Typography>
                            <Typography className={classes.headerItem} variant='subtitle1'>{xxx}</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
                    <PropertyView prjData={xxx} onChangeData={props.onChangeData}/>
                </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
```

How can I have the Accordion row colors alternate between two colors. For example blue color for odd accordion rows and green for even rows?

I want to do this dynamically and not manually by setting a special className to each row.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to style the alternate `Accordion` dynamically use the `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` in a container or wrapper elements which wraps all the `Accordion`.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  parentWrapper: {
    width: '100%',
    '&> :nth-child(even)':{
      '&>div':{
        backgroundColor:'pink'
      }
    },
    '&> :nth-child(odd)':{
      '&>div':{
        backgroundColor:'lightblue'
      }
    },
  },
}));
```

Add this `parentWrapper` class to the wrapper div of all the `Accordion`.  even children will be having pink background color and odd will be having lightblue background color.

```
export default function ControlledAccordions() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.parentWrapper}>
      {// All the  accordions will come inside this wrapper}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working demo:

[image: Edit lingering-star-t176n]

Comment: What should I change if I only want to set these alternate colors for accordion summary and not the whole <div>. And what should I add to your sent code if I want to change the color of expanded accordion(panel). I mean I want to change the color of the accordion summary component which is currently open.

Comment: background color only on expanding of panel or always?

Comment: Always alternate colors as you helped but only for the accordion summary not the whole div that styled in your code. And also another different color for example "red" for the expanded panel at each moment.

Comment: I've updated the codesanbox link.. please check. I'll update the answer tomorrow morning, actually, it's pretty late night here at my location. https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-star-t176n

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply and help. How we can have a third color on accordion summary when it is expanded.For example, "General Settings", which is the first row is red. I want it to turn gray when it expands and go "red" again when it closes. The same thing happens to the "user", that is, normally it is green when closed and gray when it expands.

Comment: @EmiliaJones I've made the changes accordingly... I can't stop myself from asking, what else (or how many more) requirements (doubts) do you have in this? :)

Comment: Sorry, but I think I explained badly, as I had the same requirement from the beginning. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Your welcome. If it helped please consider upvoting the answer. No need to be sorry. if you need any help, feel free to ask, I'll do what I can.

Comment: Thank you so much.Yes, that was great and helped me. I wanted to upvote your answer, but it says "You need 15 reputation to upvote comments.".